# Designing an algorithm to check combinations

Tags: algorithm, performance, loops, matching

I´m having serious performance issues with a job that is running everyday and I think i cannot improve the algorithm; so I´m gonnga explain you what is the problem to solve and the algorithm we have, and maybe you have some other ideas to solve the problem better.

So the problem we have to solve is:

- There is a set of Rules, ~ 120.000 Rules.
- Every rule has a set of combinations of Codes. Codes are basically strings. So we have ~8 combinations per rule. Example of a combination: TTAAT;ZZUHH;GGZZU;WWOOF;SSJJW;FFFOLL
- There is a set of Objects, ~800 objects.
- Every object has a set of ~200 codes.

We have to **check** for every Rule, if there is at least one Combination of Codes that is fully contained in the Objects. It means =>

```
loop in Rules
   Loop in Combinations of the rule
       Loop in Objects
            every code of the combination found in the Object? => create relationship rule/object and continue with the next object
       end of loop
   end of loop
end of loop
```

**For example**, if we have the Rule with this combination of two codes: HHGGT; ZZUUF
And let´s say we have an object with this codes: HHGGT; DHZZU; OIJUH; ZHGTF; **HHGGT**; JUHZT; **ZZUUF**; TGRFE; UHZGT; FCDXS

Then we create a relationship between the Object and the Rule because every code of the combination of the rule is contained in the codes of the object => this is what the algorithm has to do.

As you can see this is quite expensive, because we need 120.000 x 8 x 800 = 750 millions of times in the worst-case scenario.

This is a simplified scenario of the real problem; actually what we do in the loops is a little bit more complicated, that´s why we have to reduce this somehow.

I tried to think in a solution but I don´t have any ideas!

Do you see something wrong here?

Best regards and thank you for the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work better if I'm understanding correctly (this is in python):

```
RULES = [
    ['abc', 'def',], 
    ['aaa', 'sfd',],
    ['xyy', 'eff',]]

OBJECTS = [
    ('rrr', 'abc', 'www', 'def'), 
    ('pqs', 'llq', 'aaa', 'sdr'), 
    ('xyy', 'hjk', 'fed', 'eff'), 
    ('pnn', 'rrr', 'mmm', 'qsq')  
]   


MapOfCodesToObjects = {}
for obj in OBJECTS:
    for code in obj: 
            if (code in MapOfCodesToObjects):
                    MapOfCodesToObjects[code].add(obj)
            else:   
                    MapOfCodesToObjects[code] = set({obj})

RELATIONS = []

for rule in RULES:
    if (len(rule) == 0):
            continue
    if (rule[0] in MapOfCodesToObjects):
            ValidObjects = MapOfCodesToObjects[rule[0]]
    else:   
            continue
    for i in range(1, len(rule)):
            if (rule[i] in MapOfCodesToObjects):
                    codeObjects = MapOfCodesToObjects[rule[i]]
            else:   
                    ValidObjects = set() 
                    break   
            ValidObjects = ValidObjects.intersection(codeObjects)
            if (len(ValidObjects) == 0):
                    break   
    for vo in ValidObjects:
            RELATIONS.append((rule, vo))


for R in RELATIONS:
    print(R)
```

First you build a map of codes to objects. If there are nObj objects and nCodePerObj codes on average per object, this takes `O(nObj*nCodePerObj * log(nObj*nCodePerObj)`.

Next you iterate through the rules and look up each code in each rule in the map you built. There is a relation if a certain object occurs for every code in the rule, i.e. if it is in the set intersection of the objects for every code in the rule. Since hash lookups have O(1) time complexity on average, and set intersection has time complexity `O(min of the lengths of the 2 sets)`, this will take `O(nRule * nCodePerRule * nObjectsPerCode)`, (note that is nObjectsPerCode, not nCodePerObj, the performance gets worse when one code is included in many objects).